# Thread running an infinite loop : is this behaviour normal?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am new to multithreading. I have created a thread that only runs an infinite loop, it executes the following function :

```
while (1)
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "from thread3", "from thread3", 1);

    }
```

What I don't understand, is why my application is blocked (i.e the other threads are asleep) when this thread is created. I mean, the thread is running normally (I see the log messages), but it looks like it predates my two other threads so they are eternally paused. Shouldn't the scheduler take care of this and switch between threads ?

Details : this thread is created from c++ side using std::threads.

Comment: The scheduler isn't an magician. In your tight loop there is almost no possibility for the scheduler to step in and take control. And you're probably downvoted because  *This question doesn't show any research and is not useful*

Comment: @rene in desktop machines the scheduler can do that just fine using timer interrupts. If android uses cooperative multitasking (which makes sense), it would be nice to find a link documenting that.

Comment: I did research but couldn't find a similar case. My assumption was that the scheduler could execute say 10 times my loop, run my other threads, return back to my thread etc..

Comment: @hahaha1256 if you did research it would help your question if you shared with us what made you think exhausting a thread with this theoritcial piece of code would work flawlessly...

Comment: `while (1)` is a typical **infinite loop**! Please, learn some informatic basics.

Comment: @rene - would '__android_log_print' not be a blocking call?  It kinda implies disk I/O, which is not typically CPU-intensive, would block and so cause a scheduler run, (?)

Comment: @MartinJames I have no idea, I don't know how Google intended the use of that call nor it's implementation details. This could become a great question if the OP added that kind of detail and reasoning you applied...

Comment: @MartinJames the OP assumes it's a non-blocking call anyways. Also, I'm kinda surprised that Android doesn't have user-level preemptive multitasking. Even Nokia 5230 has a hardware button to invoke the task list that seems to be able to preempt the currently running task.

Comment: @Der Golem Yes but I am running it in a separate thread, so it shouldn't block my other threads. My understanding was that the scheduler would give "fair amount of time" to the threads so they can all run. Maybe the problem comes from the fact I am creating this thread from the native (c++) side and using std::threads.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the scheduler to pause your thread, you have to make it let go and pause periodically. Use sleep().

Comment: Note that doing this is always almost a sure sign of a bad design

Comment: @JanDvorak is that so? Why would you say so?

Comment: Almost always a proper synchronization should be used instead, such as a good ol' mutex (or even semaphore), an event queue, a producer/consumer queue (or its special case constrained to one element only, called m-box in Haskell)... The only cases I can think of are _very_ time-sensitive loops where you _know_ the other thread will finish soon (that is, you _know_ you're running at a multicore architecture and you're willingly trading compatibility for performance). Even when you're implementing said synchronisation primitives on os-level, you should have each thread know what it's waiting for

Comment: @JanDvorak I see. Thanks! Makes sense. I wasn't thinking in terms of the thread waiting *for* another resource, but yes that would mostly be the case. There are still situations where sleep is the only solution, though. Like if you want to redraw a frame of an animation after the appropriate time has passed.

Comment: @vipluv that is a legitimate use indeed. Not sure about android, but browser javascript provides a function specifically for that purpose, called "requestAnimationFrame", which is essentially a sleep scheduled to run at 60 FPS. Also be sure to check how much time has actually passed in the engine thread so that the game doesn't run slower when you're low on resources (unless you need bit-precise computation with time step undisturbed by real-world phenomena, in which case you should still run multiple ticks or sleep less so that you keep a steady pace)